# How can I convert TrueType font to PCL5 Soft font?

Tags: printing, truetype, printer-control-language

How can I convert a TrueType font to PCL5 softfont(.spf) ?
The main idea is to embed the softfont in the PCL5 printing file, then select it to use by the printer true it's stated font ID with PCL5 commands.

Also if you know a better way of using TrueType fonts in creating PCL5 file, I am opened to suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old post and the the OP has moved on, but in case anyone comes around to this, you can use the utility [PCL Paraphernalia](https://github.com/michaelknigge/pclparaphernalia).

Go to Tool > Soft Font Generate

[image]
[image]