# Convert PCL to PDF using ghostscript: cyrillic problem

Tags: ghostscript, cyrillic, pcl6

I have simple PCL file in Windows 1251 code page:

```
<ESC>E<ESC>&l6D<ESC>&a1L<ESC>&l1E<ESC>(9R<ESC>(s0p10.00h0s0b4099T
Привет! (it means Hello!)
```

When I convert it to pdf with gpcl6win32.exe from ghostscript 9.28:

```
gpcl6win32.exe -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dNOCACHE -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pcl
```

I get unreadable cyrillic glyphs in output.pdf because there are no cyrillic glyphs in NimbusMono-Regular selected for Courier font (4099):
[image]

What is correct way to make it correct PDF with cyrillic glyphs?

Thank you for any hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a font which contains Cyrillic glyphs. The simplest solution is to embed a soft font in the PCL. Otherwise you could **try** defining a different Courier font by editing fontmap.GS.

If you want to try that you will need to find a version of Courier which contains the Cyrillic glyphs, since you are presumably using Windows, you could try using the Windows version of Courier.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have found perfect tool here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40255509/how-can-i-convert-truetype-font-to-pcl5-soft-font/55504671#55504671 to generate pcl soft font from ttf.